# Creating new identity in ADF

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-data-factory

i am working on ADF , i am loading data from adls to sql server through a pipeline.
I want to create a ID in my pipeline that can be used as an identity to show the data of that particular run in the database.

In each run, there should be unique id created, through which we can refer to all the data which is loaded to DB in that particular run

I don't know how to create that.
Can we run anu sql statement to create the ID and use it later in pipeline parameters?

Comment: you can use pipeline run Id as unique id for each iteration

Answer (score 0):

To create identity for every new iteration of pipeline you can use two ways as follows.

- **Pipeline run Id:**
  **Each pipeline run has a unique pipeline run ID**. You can use it as unique id for each pipeline run and store it in sql table as below:
  [image]
  [image]
  **Output for it**
  [image]
- Run SQL statement to create the ID and then store it in Azure sql.
  You can use Lookup activity to run SQL statement on database and create an Id.
  [image]
  Store the output of SQL statement as unique id.[image]
  Mapping is same as above.

**Output for this:**
[image]